# Space of NULL values?

Tags: mysql

If I have a column CHAR(100) and is allowed to have NULL values, when the value is NULL, how much space will this take?

Also, will there be a performance hit, considering the column will be written only one, never updated and selected a lot of times?

Comment: Not enough information are provided there

Answer (score 2):

Before version 5.0.3, the default format is set to "REDUNDANT" : any fixed-length field will use the same space, even if it's value is NULL.

Starting with version 5.0.3, the value is set to "COMPACT" : **NULL values will never use any space in your database.**

read this for more deatails  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/data-size.html

Comment: Can you please be more specific about case #2, seems like a fairy tail. They must use at least one bit.